# Delay embedding for an irregularly-sampled time series

Tags: time-series

I'm interested in exploring some time series from the point of view of a delay embedding and [Taken's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takens%27_theorem). All the examples I have seen of time delay embedding involve regularly (evenly) sampled time series where lagged versions of the observed series can easily be created.

However, I am interested in time series that are *irregularly* sampled in time. By this I mean observations are not at integer time points with perhaps some missing observations, but as observations of a continuous process taken at irregular intervals.

Is there a way to create a time delay embedding of such irregular time series? If there are, can such embeddings be used in the context of Taken's theorem?

Answer (score 2):

As usual, the answer is "it depends".

There are some generalizations of Takens that obviate the need for regularly sampled time series, by using multi-dimensional time series (see [Sauer et al. 1991](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01053745), [Stark et al. 1997](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0362546X96001496), [Stark et al. 2003](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00332-003-0534-4), [Deyle & Sugihara 2011](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0018295)).

Alternatively, if the data are only a "little" irregularly sampled, then you might be able to treat it as process error. I recommend [Casdagli et al. 1991](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016727899190222U) as an excellent reference on this topic.

For anything fancier, maybe contact me and we can write a paper together. ;)